# Winsorize DataFrame based on Groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, statsmodels

I have made the following replicable example:

```
col1 = pd.Series(['2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31'])
col2 = pd.Series(['Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv','Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr','Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv'])
col3 = pd.Series(['Eq', 'Eq', 'Eq' , 'Bond','Bond','Bond', 'Eq', 'Eq', 'Eq' , 'Bond','Bond','Bond', 'Eq', 'Eq', 'Eq' , 'Bond','Bond','Bond', 'Eq', 'Eq', 'Eq' , 'Bond','Bond','Bond'])
col4 = pd.Series([5,3,200, 5,7,23,5,4,21,68,45,324,32,4,78,2,45,2,56,3,5,7,22,45])
Example = pd.DataFrame(data = pd.concat([col1,col2,col3,col4], axis=1))
Example.columns =  ['Date', 'InType', 'AType', 'Value']
```

Which looks as follows: 
[image]

I want to winsorize the 'Value' column at the 1% level by first grouping on 'Date', 'Intype', and 'Atype'. For instance, the first group of the column that I want to winsorize has date 2016-04-30, Intype = Discr, and AType = Eq. In this case I would want the 200 to be set equal to 5. I want to do this for all the groups seperately.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
def using_mstats_df(df):
    return df.apply(using_mstats, axis=0)

def using_mstats(s):
    return mstats.winsorize(s, limits=[0.0, 0.5])
grouped = Example.groupby(['Date', 'InType', 'AType'])
grouped.apply(using_mstats_df)
```

It seems to do the correct thing, but when I try it on my actual (big) dataset, I get a very large error which ends with

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong, or perhaps I should do it in a different way?

Comment: Could you add an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example (I am not 100% sure about Winsorizing)

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats

col1 = pd.Series(['2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-04-30','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31','2016-05-31'])
col2 = pd.Series(['Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv','Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr','Discr','Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv', 'Adv'])
col3 = pd.Series(['Eq', 'Eq', 'Eq' , 'Bond','Bond','Bond', 'Eq', 'Eq', 'Eq' , 'Bond','Bond','Bond', 'Eq', 'Eq', 'Eq' , 'Bond','Bond','Bond', 'Eq', 'Eq', 'Eq' , 'Bond','Bond','Bond'])
col4 = pd.Series([5,3,200, 5,7,23,5,4,21,68,45,324,32,4,78,2,45,2,56,3,5,7,22,45])
df = pd.DataFrame(data = pd.concat([col1,col2,col3,col4], axis=1))
df.columns =  ['Date', 'InType', 'AType', 'Value']

# sort your df
df = df.sort_values(['Date', 'InType', 'AType'])

# empty list to store the values column after winsorization
winsorized_values = []

# winsorize every group
for name, group in df.groupby(['Date', 'InType', 'AType']):
    winsorized_values.append(list(scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize(group.Value.values, limits=[0.01, 0.99])))

# append the winsorized values to dataframe, after flatening the list
df['winsorized_values'] = [item for sublist in winsorized_values for item in sublist]
```